# Magical Record cascade delete (truncateAll) not deleting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record in my app.

I have a relationship...

```
Competition <-->> League
```

i.e. A `Competition` can have many `Leagues`. A `League` can only have one `Competition`.

The delete rule from `Competition to League` is set to `Cascade`. The inverse delete rule is set to `Nullify`.

What I would expect to happen is if I delete a `Competition` then all `Leagues` that belong to it are deleted also. (I have used this in previous apps successfully).

I am testing by doing...

1. Download and insert all competitions and leagues.
2. Log all Leagues with Competition names.

   ```
   NSArray *leagues = [League findAll];
   for (League *league in *leagues)
   {
       NSLog(@"%@ - %@", league.name, league.competition.name);
   }

   e.g. Man UTD - Premier League
   ```
3. run the following code...

   ```
   [Competition truncateAll];
   ```
4. Log all Leagues with Competition names.

   ```
   e.g. Man UTD - (null)
   ```

I was expecting this to delete the `Leagues` as well as the `Competitions`?

Is my assumption correct in what it should do? Why isn't it doing it?

Comment: How do you "Log all Leagues with Competition names"? Do you fetch them again or do you use existing pointers to the objects? - Note that the delete rules are only applied when you `save` the context or call `processPendingChanges`.

Comment: Edited to show log code. I thought that truncateAll did that? I'm being stupid. I wrapped the truncate in a save block and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship delete rules are applied when the managed object
context is *saved*, or `processPendingChanges` is called.

As can be seen in the [implementation](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject%2BMagicalRecord.m), the MagicalRecord method `MR_truncateAll` calls
`deleteObject` on all objects of an entity, but does not save the context.

Comment: Does it delete the database too?

Comment: @user1007522: No, it deletes all objects of the given entity, e.g. `[Car truncateAll];` deletes all Car objects from the database. There can be other entities which are not affected. The SQLite file itself is not deleted.

Comment: @MartinR, well, and how could I delete whole database content?

Comment: @gaussblurinc Did you find out a solution to delete whole database? Does `[magicalrecord cleanup]` works?

Comment: @ZigiiWong no, `[MagicalRecord CleanUp]` cleanup magical record stack with coordinators, stores, contexts. You could cleanup database by wiping all content from all tables OR wiping database file ( if you use sqlite ). Have a look at a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lolgear/54cbbc7a5252c6c20df09ac5759550a0)

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Martin R.

Just add following lines after

```
[Competition truncateAll];

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

And you will be good to go! :)